# Calling data from firebase as per pagination

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-redux

I have firebase real-time database with a field of employee having more than 2000 entries having details of all employees. In my react-app while fetching the list of employees , I have to first fetch the whole employee field data to display the entries causing a lot of loading time.

Is there any way so that i could be able to query for only 10 entries of employee for the 1st page and while clicking for next page it again fetches the next 10 entries, Because doing so while reduce the time for loading the screens ...

Answer (score 2):

Yes surely firebase seems to give the feature of filtering list.

You can use limitToFirst() and startAt(), to implement pagination and get limited data.

For more information you can go with docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#filtering_data

Comment: As per the docs , I have read if I will use limitToFirst(10) it will only show 10 entries. Now , what I need is that I will be requiring data from from 11 to 20 when I click on 2page on pagination .. Can You Just Explain the login to me in short. It would be a great pleasure.

Comment: You can use the orderByKey() method to first sort the data according to key, then pull 1st 10 results, save the last result key and then again pull the next 10 records starting with the key saved  orderByKey().limitToFirst(10).startAtKey(lastKeySaved),  then repeat the last two steps till you get all records.

Comment: And what type of listener you would suggest to use query.on('value') or query.once('value') ? @RajSaraogi